# How to avoid lazy evaluation in a function that appends an element to each of its vector arguments?

Tags: r

### The problem

If I have a list of, say, three vectors:

```
Lv <- list(c(1,2), c(3,3), c(5,3))
```

it is easy to append an additional and the same element to each vector of the list, as follows:

```
lapply(Lv, c, 8)
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 2 8
##
## [[2]]
## [1] 3 3 8
##
## [[3]]
## [1] 5 3 8
```

However, if I try to apply this same technique inside a function in the following way,

```
append8 <- function(p1, p2, p3, ...) {
    Args <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
    lapply(Args, c, 8)
}
```

the result is disastrous:

```
append8(c(1,2), c(3,3), c(5,3))
## $p1
## $p1[[1]]
## c(1, 2)
##
## $p1[[2]]
## [1] 8
##    
## $p2
## $p2[[1]]
## c(3, 3)
##
## $p2[[2]]
## [1] 8
##    
## $p3
## $p3[[1]]
## c(5, 3)
##
## $p3[[2]]
## [1] 8
```

Debugging the function **append8**, I found that the **Args** list is composed in an unusual manner

```
Args
## $p1
## c(1, 2)
## 
## $p2
## c(3, 3)
## 
## $p3
## c(5, 3)
```

which, I guess, is due to the R lazy evaluation. Do you know if there is a way to avoid it?

Comment: My expected output is the same of the second code block, the one that  begins with 'lapply(Lv, c, 8)'.

Comment: You could use `eval`, I think. As in, `lapply(yourlist, eval)` which forces evaluation.

Comment: Maybe send the arguments in a `list` then ? `append8(list(c(1,2), c(3,3), c(5,3)))` ? where `append8` is `append8 <- function(lst) {
  lapply(lst, c, 8)
}`

Comment: Args <- list(p1, p2, p3, ...)

Comment: And this has nothing to do with lazy evaluation. You are not understanding what match.call does.

Comment: Could you broaden your explanation? What does match.call do?

Comment: It does exactly what you have observed: It returns the (unevaluated) call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. There may be a better way, however. Applying `eval` to each list element forces the evaluation of the parsed components of the call.

```
 append8 <- function(p1, p2, p3, ...) {
   Args <- as.list(match.call())[-1]
   l <- lapply(Args, eval)
   lapply(l, c, 8)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Super late to the party, but I stumble dupon this question and while the accepted answers answers the surfacing problem, I just want to elaborate why this happened, and what you should do insted (spoiler: **DO NOT USE eval**)

`match.call` returns a *call*. Hence if you want to have the values which this *call* evaluates to, you have tom well, `eval`uate it.

However, this is overly complicated and not how you should do it in `R` in the first place.

Your goal is to create a function which appends `8` to each argument and your function should accept an arbitrary number of elements. Maybe you want to treat the first 3 arguments in a special way, so it would be good to force the user to supply at least three arguments with the option to provide more. So instead of using `match.call` you can simply use `list` and `...` like this:

```r
append8 <- function(p1, p2, p3, ...) {
  args <- list(p1, p2, p3, ...)
  lapply(args, c, 8)
}

# you can use the function with 3...
append8(c(1,2), c(3,3), c(5,3))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 8

# [[2]]
# [1] 3 3 8

# [[3]]
# [1] 5 3 8

# ... or more arguments ...
append8(2:3, 4:5, 6:7, 8:9)
# [[1]]
# [1] 2 3 8

# [[2]]
# [1] 4 5 8

# [[3]]
# [1] 6 7 8

# [[4]]
# [1] 8 9 8


# ... but not with less
append8(1:2, 3:4)
# Error in append8(1:2, 3:4) : argument "p3" is missing, with no default
```

If you do not want to have 3 elements at minimum you would define `append8` like this:

```r
append8 <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  lapply(args, c, 8)
}
```